# Building Relations between ObjecTypes in Typgraphql and Prisma

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I am trying to create a relation between 2 ObjecTypes in Typgraphql with Apollo. This is my error:

[image]

As you can see in my category section I get null. This should be an item, because I already see it in my prisma ORM

```
  @FieldResolver(() => Category)
    async categories(@Root() parent: Product, @Ctx() ctx:Context): Promise<Category[]> {
        return await ctx.prisma.category.findUnique({
            where: {id: parent.id}
        }).categories()!  
    }
```

I created a FieldResolver that returns the category when running the product's id. However, when I run categories at the end I get the following error: **Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'Prisma__CategoryClient<Category | null>'**.

I don't why I am getting this issue. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `.categories()!` at the end? In the image is shown `category` but the method name is `categories`. Moreover, the Prisma query looks odd to me. Can you share the prisma model to show how the mapping between Product and Category is done?